# Error ArrayList when get null string from EditText

Tags: android, arraylist, android-edittext

When edittext is null and press add button my code crash...I try to copy integers from edittext to an Array...How i can fix it this error? i have set edittext
       android:inputType="numberDecimal"

Can i put try...catch?

```
  public static ArrayList<Integer> pulseslist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public int pulses1[]=null;

  private OnClickListener btnAddListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String ag=editIRpulse1.getText().toString().trim();
            if (ag!=null){
            int intag= Integer.parseInt(ag);
            if(ag.length() > 0){
                   pulseslist.add(intag); 
                   editIRpulse1.setText(""); // adds text to arraylist and make edittext blank again

            }   

            pulses1 = new int[pulseslist.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < pulseslist.size(); i++) {
                pulses1[i] = pulseslist.get(i);
            }

            }
        }

    };
```

Comment: Can you add a stack trace detailing which line the null pointer occurs on?

Comment: I try to find something to LogCat...but nothing...no errors...

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

to

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Since you want only `int`s. You also should use a `try/catch` to catch a `NumberFormatException` to prevent empty `Strings` or numbers that are invalid. Just don't do nothing if you catch an exception. You should display a message to the user that they have enetered invalid characters

Comment: I have on create:  editIRpulse1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

Comment: Then post your logcat. It's likely you are getting a `NumberFormatException` or your `Button` is `null` but could be something else. Hard to say without logcat

Comment: Integer.invalidInt(String) line: 138

Comment: I'm guessing that's this line, `int intag= Integer.parseInt(ag);`? you need to do error checking to make sure it is an `int`

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to accept the answer I will edit it to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> pulseslist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public int pulses1[]=null;

  private OnClickListener btnAddListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String ag=editIRpulse1.getText().toString();
            if (ag!=null){
            ag.trim(); //Maybe crash for this method put here........................
            int intag= Integer.parseInt(ag);
            if(ag.length() > 0){
                   pulseslist.add(intag); 
                   editIRpulse1.setText(""); // adds text to arraylist and make edittext blank again

            }   

            pulses1 = new int[pulseslist.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < pulseslist.size(); i++) {
                pulses1[i] = pulseslist.get(i);
            }

            }
        }

    };
```